# How to list all inbox SMS in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to show all SMS in Phone when press button. Information to show display is phone number and content message.

I already have method to receive SMS when someone send to me (app run or background) but not have solution to get all SMS immediately. (Xamarin.Forms)

I try code below but get error in ContentResolver.Query(uri, reqCols, null, null, null);
=> CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'

```
string[] items;
    public void getAllSms()
    {
        string INBOX = "content://sms/inbox";
        string[] reqCols = new string[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type" };
        Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(INBOX);
        var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, reqCols, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String messageId = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[0]));
                String threadId = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[1]));
                String address = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[2]));
                String name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[3]));
                String date = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[4]));
                String msg = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[5]));
                String type = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[6]));

                items = new string[] {
   ((messageId + (","
                    + (threadId + (","
                    + (address + (","
                    + (name + (","
                    + (date + (" ,"
                    + (msg + (" ," + type))))))))))))) };

            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can't do this in iOS

Comment: Let try on Android first

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about how to do this on Android: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+list+sms+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: But there are Xamarin.Android. I already try in Xamarin.Forms not work

Comment: you need to use `DependencyService` to access platform specific code from XF

Comment: Yes. I know. But method to implement in Xamarin.Android? Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you.  I just gave you a link to dozens of examples of how to do this.  If you're having a problem implementing it, then post the code that you have written and describe the specific problem you are having with it.

Comment: That's so good.

Comment: Jason could you help me fix that issue?

Comment: you need to get an instance of `ContentResolver` from the current activity

Comment: Thanks you, i did it :D you are master

Answer (score 1):

```
    public List<string> GetAllSms()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        Android.Content.Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        string INBOX = "content://sms/inbox";
        string[] reqCols = new string[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type" };
        Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(INBOX);
        var cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, reqCols, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String messageId = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[0]));
                String threadId = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[1]));
                String address = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[2]));
                String name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[3]));
                String date = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[4]));
                String msg = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[5]));
                String type = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(reqCols[6]));

                list.Add(address);

                items = new string[] {
   ((messageId + (","
                    + (threadId + (","
                    + (address + (","
                    + (name + (","
                    + (date + (" ,"
                    + (msg + (" ," + type))))))))))))) };

            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());

        }

        return list;
    }
```